# Can´t open word file with XMLHttpRequest

Tags: ms-word, xmlhttprequest, document

I'm trying to open a word file with XMLHttpRequest with javascript and I can't.
Can anyone help to solve it?
The code I'm using is:

Untitled 5

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 5</title>
<script type="text/javascript">


    try{
        var abreficheiro = new XMLHttpRequest();                   
        abreficheiro.open('GET', 'cir_entidade.doc');
        abreficheiro.setRequestHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment');         
        abreficheiro.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/msword');            
        abreficheiro.send();
        }
catch(err) {
        var strErr = 'Error:';
        strErr +='\\nNumber:'+err.number;
        strErr +='\\nDescription:'+err.description;
        document.write(strErr);
    }

</script>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this way to do it
Just replace ${filename} with the name of the file.
Works in chrome and edge

```
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("GET", "${filename}.doc");
        request.responseType = "blob";
        request.onload = function() {
          // set `blob` `type` to `"text/html"`;
          var blob = new Blob([this.response], {type:"application/msword"});
          var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          var w = window.open(url);
        }
        request.send();
```